# Traffic light synchronization problem

Tags: code-challenge, math, graph-theory

I'm not a 100% sure if this qualifies under this stack exchange; however, I asked [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5814/help-in-setting-up-and-solving-a-transportation-traffic-problem) on the stats stackexchange with no answers. I wonder if you can solve it:

[Traffic light synchronization](http://ops.fhwa.dot.gov/publications/fhwahop08024/chapter6.htm) nowadays is not a tedious project, Image:

[image]

For a personal research project I'm trying to build a statistical model to solve such problems in two and higher dimensions.

I would like to synchronize `x` 4 legged (approaches) intersections such that:

- The intersections are all located within the same area in a grid type format. I'd like to think of this as a 1/0 matrix, where 1 indicates a signalized intersection and 0 doesn't:

  **Matrix Example**

  [1 1 1 1]

  [0 1 0 1]

  [1 1 1 1]

  This assumes that all nodes are connected in a vertical or horizontal but not diagonal manner and that they could have a direction of either one or two way.
- Each Intersection has a traffic light on each approach
- The allowable movements per leg are left, right, and Through (lrt) and no U-Turns
- Each Leg can be one lane, i.e. one lane that allows for lrt or approaches can have combined, through and right (1 lane), and left (1 lane, or dedicated such as alpha left lanes, beta through lanes, and gamma right lanes. Some intersections should allow for restricted or no movement, as in an intersection could be setup as "no-left turns allowed"
- Each lane should have a distinct vehicle flow (vehicles / minutes (Time)) per movement, so a two lane (left + through, and right) approach could have the following movement:

  Left + Through lane: 10 vehicles / minute (through) and 5 vehicles per minute turning left

  Right lane: 15 vehicles per minute
- Assume green cycle time (time from beginning of green to beginning second green to depend on the vehicle volumes, yet could only be between t1 and t2 seconds. Green time = red time + yellow time). Yellow time should be assumed as a constant either 1, 2, or 3 seconds (depending on the jurisdiction). if pedestrian crossing is warranted, the red time should be assumed to be "white go ped: 4 seconds x lane" + "blinking ped: 4 seconds x lane". remember that the number of lanes would be from the opposing approaches combined.
- The system should optimize green time so that maximum flow is passed through the system at all intersections depending no the existing volumes **and** on historical values.
- Although there are historical data on the number of vehicles that enter the green network, I assume it is best to use a Monte Carlo simulation to simulate vehicle entry into the system and then calibrated to historical data.
- The end result should be an equation or system of equations that will give you the green time for each intersection depending on volumes and what to expect from the other intersections.

I know this might not be the clearest question, but I'm happy to answer any questions and or comments.

Comment: Welcome to CodeGolf.SE! This is a site for posting programming *games*, and I'm not at all sure that this qualifies as it appears to define a major (and actually quite interesting) research project. I am closing this for now, but am willing to be convinced if I have made a mistake.

Comment: Actually, I agree with you somewhat, and perhaps, it could be migrated to the programmer's stack exchange? the biggest reason, I posted here, is that for the most part, code golfers are looking for a good challenge to solve

Comment: It would be off-topic on Programmers and Stack Overflow.  I would think it would be more on-topic on [Math] than on Stats.  Or perhaps [cstheory].

Comment: sure, feel free to migrate the question to any stack exchange that you see fit

Comment: since no one has migrated the question, I'm going to put a bounty on stats for it